# How to apply boolean on liquid?

Tags: modifiers, fluid-simulation

I want to create a fluid injection like effect in a solid. For this maybe I can use the boolean modifier. But how to select the fluid on which I have to apply because fluid is not inflowing from a circle in a solid cube.

Comment: Hey there and welcome. If i may **think aloud**, you would need to create the geometry of the shape you want the fluid to follow/fill. Eventually even rotated so it fills from down upwards. Simulate the filling of that, bake it and adjust the rotation to the object/cube you mentioned. Afterwards you should be able to use a boolean modifier with both objects to create the result. This is only a though up solution, thus not an answer, at most a suggestion.

Comment: Thanks @Xylvier for the suggestion. I will try it.